# How to solve the $2^{nd}$ order diff. eq. using laplace if we are given y(0) and y'(1)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the $2^{nd}$ order diff. eq. using laplace transform if we are given y(0) and y'(1)?

Thanks

Comment: You mean $y'(0)$. You need to know how to find the Lalace transform of the derivative.

Comment: The problem is that I mean y'(1). That is my problem. So, do you have any ideas?

Comment: DEQ? What does it mean?

Comment: Differential Equation = DEQ

Comment: $y''+3y'+2y=t+u(t-\pi)\cos t$

Answer (score 2):

Given:

$$ay'' + by' + c y = f(t), y(0) = w, y'(1) = v$$

We have:

$$\mathcal{L}(ay'' + by' + c y = f(t))(s) = a(s^2 y(s) - s y(0) - y'(0))+ b(sy(s) - y(0)) + cy(s) = F(s)$$

Substitute the single IC at time $t=0$, solve this for $y(s)$, do partial fractions and then find the inverse transform.

You will be carrying the $y'(0)$ initial condition throughout this calculation as an unknown, call it $y'(0) = d$.

Once you have found the solution for $y(t)$, you then find the derivative, substitute in $y'(1)$ and solve for the constant $d$.

Comment: But here y'(1) is given instead of y'(0)

Comment: Another +1 for your cap!

Comment: @amWhy: At first, I was confused by this given the disparate times. It is now clear, but this is a nasty result nonetheless. :-) Thanks for the support - off to the showers/gym/presentation/errands.

Comment: Nice;y done :+)

Comment: @B.S.: Thank you and have a great day!